# Creating new folders if they don't exist for fopen

Tags: c++, windows, fopen, mkdir

I have a C++ program that takes user input for `fopen` in order to initiate a file write. Could someone help me find a function which will return a `FILE*` and use the Windows specific version of `mkdir` in order to create the folder structure for `fopen` to never fail to open a new file in the specified location because one of the folders does not exist. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's a method MakeSureDirectoryPathExists in the windows API, declared in dbghelp.h. It recursively creates directories, so I guess that's what you are after.
However, there is NO way of making sure this 'never fails' as you ask, as it also depends on privileges etc if you have write access to a certain directory.

edit: here's some dummy sample code; it uses GetProcAddress though, as I couldn't find the dbghelp header when I wrote it.

```
typedef BOOL (WINAPI * CreateDirFun ) ( __in PCSTR DirPath );

HMODULE h = LoadLibrary( "dbghelp.dll" );
CreateDirFun pFun = (CreateDirFun) GetProcAddress( h, "MakeSureDirectoryPathExists" );
(*m_pFun)( psPath ) )
CreateDirectory( psPath );
FreeLibrary( h );
```

Comment: Well, that's just what I was looking for. Thanks again!

Comment: I think it would make more sense to use SHCreateDirectoryEX.

Comment: MSDN explicitly states for SHCreateDirectoryEx: "This function is available through Windows XP Service Pack 2 (SP2) and Windows Server 2003. It might be altered or unavailable in subsequent versions of Windows." So its a not good choice if the program will be distributed accross many users. May be a good choice if this function is part of small utility that will be used only by author himself.