# To create all needed folders with fopen

Tags: c, fopen

I'm using `fopen("aaa\bbb\ccc\myfile.txt","w")` to create output file. But folders `aaa`, `bbb` and `ccc` don't exist. What is the best way to solve this problem? Is there are any standard way to ask `fopen()` to create all needed folders?

Comment: No, `fopen` will never make directories. There's a [question with good answers already](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336242/recursive-mkdir-system-call-on-unix/11425692) about an extended `mkdir()` that makes multiple levels, which is similar to what you want. You'd need to do that multi-level mkdir on `"aaa/bbb/ccc/"` then call `fopen`.

Comment: For windows you could use information in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834737/creating-new-folders-if-they-dont-exist-for-fopen

Comment: Remember to double those backslashes, in general that is. Won't help with the problem since `fopen()` simply doesn't support creating directories, but *if* the dirs existed it would be necessary.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley Why not answer instead of make a comment? So the author would be able to close this question.

Comment: Folders are a GUI artefact. What the file system deals with is [directories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_(computing)) and they are operating system specific. Standard C11 does not know about directories

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, there is no cross-platform support for directories in the C standard library.

As far as my understanding goes, `fopen()` and friends don't even know or care that the `/`-es or `\`-es in the path you give them are used as directory separators in the two major operating system families in use today.

For a cross-platform solution for *single* directory creation, see @dbush 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42906151/6177253).

You can then wrap this with a function of your own that will take the complete file/directory path including all parent folders and create all the required parent folders (if needed), one-by-one.

For this, you will need to devise a way of extracting out each successive parent directory from your file path, starting from the top-most/left-most directory. Take care with splitting strings in C, as functions like `strtok()` can be unsafe —you might be better off with a different approach for converting the path into a list of directories to create.

You may also need to handle cases where directories already exist, or where a file exists at a path where you wanted to place one of your directories.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another alternative written in plain C, and that does not rely on `strtok` (which mangles the passed file path string):

```
const char pathSeparator =
#ifdef _WIN32
  '\\';
#else
  '/';
#endif

// Given a file path, create all constituent directories if missing
void create_file_path_dirs(char *file_path) {
  char *dir_path = (char *) malloc(strlen(file_path) + 1);
  char *next_sep = strchr(file_path, pathSeparator);
  while (next_sep != NULL) {
    int dir_path_len = next_sep - file_path;
    memcpy(dir_path, file_path, dir_path_len);
    dir_path[dir_path_len] = '\0';
    mkdir(dir_path, S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IROTH);
    next_sep = strchr(next_sep + 1, pathSeparator);
  }
  free(dir_path);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can mix some C++ in your program, boost.filesystem library has a very handy [function](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#create_directories) to create all intermediate directories.

bool create_directories(const path& p);

Answer (score 0):

The C Std. Lib. functions for opening and writing-to files, while they can create new files in existing directories, they cannot create new directories. To do that, I suggest using the "mkdir" function from header "sys/stat.h" and the "chdir" function from header "unistd.h".

For example, if writing a C program to be used on Cygwin on Windows 10, something like this would work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <error.h>
int main (void)
{
   FILE * fp;
   chdir("/cygdrive/d");
   if (mkdir("aaa", S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IROTH))
   {
      error(EXIT_FAILURE, errno, "Failed to create directory aaa");
   }
   chdir("aaa");
   if (mkdir("bbb", S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IROTH))
   {
      error(EXIT_FAILURE, errno, "Failed to create directory bbb");
   }
   chdir("bbb");
   if (mkdir("ccc", S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IROTH))
   {
      error(EXIT_FAILURE, errno, "Failed to create directory ccc");
   }
   chdir("ccc");
   fp=fopen("MyFile.txt", "w");
   if (!fp)
   {
      error(EXIT_FAILURE, errno, "Failed to open file for writing");
   }
   fprintf(fp, "Test.\n");
   fclose(fp);
   return 0;
}
```

That will create the directory "D:\aaa\bbb\ccc", then create a file in that directory called "MyFile.txt", then write "Test.\n" to that file.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not as elegant as other ones but:

```
system("mkdir aaa\\bbb\\ccc\\");
FILE * fp;
fp = fopen("aaa/bbb/ccc/myfile.txt","w");
```

For linux use `-p` option and slashes.

backslashes should be in `system()` function if you're using Windows

Comment: @andreee True, but the folder path looks as from Windows.

Comment: The backslashes should be escaped, and could be replaced by slashes.

Comment: Forgot about that, thanks. If the user uses Windows, then terminal will return syntax error (and not creating the directory) if using slashes

Answer (score -1):

if you are using `fopen()` then you should create the parent directories first.

you can simply do this by

```
system("mkdir -p aaa/bbb/ccc");
fopen("aaa/bbb/ccc/myfile.txt","w");
```

don't forget to include header file `<stdlib.h>` in this program

Comment: The backslashes should be escaped, and could be replaced by slashes. The `mkdir` command might not exist or not know about `-p`

Answer (score -3):

fopen() is used to open input streams for text or binary files and not the directory files. If you want to have your file open in a path which holds non-existant directories, I'd suggest you use the mkdir() method of the /sys/stat.h header file. Once you have the directories ready you can used fopen() to open the file you need(or create it if not already present).
This is the approach that I used to create a file in the a directory of my $HOME folder:-

```
char* home_dir= getenv("HOME"); 
/*creates the directory with specified modes*/
mkdir(strcat(home_dir, "/make-a-note/"),S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IROTH | S_IXOTH); 
/*used the strcat() to generate the file-path.*/
personal_work=fopen(strcat(home_dir,"personal_work.txt"),"a+");
```

Comment: Don't use that code, the `strcat()` call is evil: It definitely overruns the buffer holding the environment variables content. This undefined behavior will likely trash some other environment variable(s), or worse.